# Load test WebAPI fileupload IIS 8.5 fail

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-web-api, load-testing, iis-8.5

I am running load test with 300 user load for 10 minutes [step load add 10 users every 10 seconds] on WebAPI service hosted on:

> CPU  Intel E5-2665 @2.40 – 4 Core/RAM 16 GB/ Windows 2012 R2/IIS 8.5

My image file size to upload is 500 KB and using Multipart/form-data to post file to WebAPI.

On WebAPI code I use `await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)` to avoid thread blocking.

On machine config modified to handle bursty load. `<processModel autoConfig="false" maxWorkerThreads="100" maxIoThreads="100" minWorkerThreads="15" minIoThreads="15" />`

IIS queue length is set as 5000, single worker process [tried multiple and 0 for NUMA too] Limit\Connection time out 180 seconds.

I started getting bellow errors, even before user count reaches 300 and once 300 is reached the error added up.

> `Exception        SocketException         26        An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
>   Exception        IOException   7          Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed`

When fewer users are added, files are uploaded in 0.13 seconds, but as load increases, the response time increases drastically.

Average response time taken: 5.72 Seconds;
Minimum response time taken: 0.13 seconds;
Maximum response  time 8.88 Seconds.

Please help. 
[image: Load test response time]